# Make it possible in 10 K tools to view all migrations to/from a specific site and give a summary

Tags: feature-request, migration, 10k-tools

I love the 10K tools. They're a lot of fun to explore.

Recently, I was participating in a discussion on Science Fiction & Fantasy about migrations to Movies & TV. I'm not a big SFF user but I do have 10K tools on M&TV. In order to quantify the numbers of migrations, you can certainly view the list of question in the migration tool view but there doesn't seem to be a way to limit the list to a specific site only. This means that, while you can certainly manually count all of the migrations, you have to avoid counting questions from other sites.

What I am requesting is that you make it possible to limit the "migrated" page results to a specific site only. So, if I'm only interested in questions sent to M&TV from SFF, instead of this:

[image: Multiple sites]

You would instead see something like this:

[image: SFF only]

In addition, it would be super cool if you added a counter that would include stats on this limited page about the history of the migrations. Something along the lines of:

> SFF migration stats:
>
> - Migrations here: 88
> - Migrations away: 21
> - Rejected here: 19
> - Rejected away: 1

This would give 10K users a quick overview on how the site's doing with migrations and, if there's a lot of rejected migrations, see what's needing to be fixed. It'd also make discussions like the one on SFF easier as you wouldn't have to manually count all of the migrations.

Comment: There is something sort of like this already, at `/tools/posts/migrated/stats`, but it (a) doesn't show a breakdown of *what* questions were migrated, and (b) only shows migrations in the last 90 days